# If condition inside a for-each loop returns all results multiplied - XSLT

Tags: if-statement, xslt, foreach

This is a part of my XML:

```
<record>
    <leader>01707nkm a2200421 i 4500</leader>
    <controlfield tag="001">9925375136006986</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="003">CZ-PrCU</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="005">20220502141021.0</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="006">m     o  c        </controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="007">gs#cd##z#</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="007">cc#cd##z#</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="008">220128q19uu1945xx nnn            s|zxx d</controlfield>
</record>
```

And this is my XSLT template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:for-each select="/record/controlfield[@tag=007]">
                
                <xsl:if test="/record/controlfield[@tag=007][substring(text(),1,1)='g'][substring(text(),2,1)='s']">
                    <form authority="marccategory">electronic resource</form>
                </xsl:if>
                
                <xsl:if test="/record/controlfield[@tag=007][substring(text(),1,1)='c'][substring(text(),2,1)='c']">
                    <form authority="marccategory">slide</form>    
                </xsl:if>
                
    
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form authority="marccategory">electronic resource</form>
<form authority="marccategory">slide</form>
<form authority="marccategory">electronic resource</form>
<form authority="marccategory">slide</form>
```

Can you help me to uderstand what am I doing wrong? Problem is that I got duplicated results. The condition should be True just in a particular field - not in both field 007.

You can see it here: http://xsltransform.net/gVhDDyG/2

The desired result which I would expect to achive by this code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form authority="marccategory">electronic resource</form>
<form authority="marccategory">slide</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/record/controlfield[@tag=007]">
```

puts you in the context of `controlfield`. From this context, the test of the **current** value should  use a **relative** path, not an **absolute** one as your attempt does - e.g.

```
<xsl:if test="substring(text(),1,1)='g' and substring(text(),2,1)='s'">
```

which I believe could be simplified to:

```
<xsl:if test="starts-with(., 'gs')">
```

I would also suggest using `xsl:choose` for mutually exclusive options instead of multiple `xsl:if` instructions.

Comment: Hi, today I tried to implement your advice into my Python script and I've found out it is not working as I expected (although it is working in this http://xsltransform.net online tool but not in my Python.. weird.). Problem is that in XSLT is considered just first "if" condition. Second one is ignored even though it should be matched. Also when I add more elements as output of the condition in reality it returns to me just first element as result. To see exactly the whole record and my XSLT I add [http://xsltransform.net/a9GPfy/1](http://xsltransform.net/a9GPfy/1)

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you because I don't know how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, I will try to figure it out. Thanks for the help anyway!